# How to in Room Database delete two tables in one query?

Tags: android, android-room

How to in Room delete two tables in one Query? I've tried this, but it doesn't work. Room does not allow the use of such a query.

```
@Query("DELETE (DELETE FROM expense_table) AND (DELETE FROM income_table)")
void deleteAllData();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use transaction
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction

```
@Transaction
 public void deleteTwo(TableEx table, TableIn table_in) {
     // Anything inside this method runs in a single transaction.
     delete(table);
     delete(table_in);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but I used two queries. Every single for one table. I think the @Transaction is perfekt for objects. Thank you for all that.

Comment: What if one of the queries fails. Did you handle that?

Comment: Even if one table is empty app doesn't crashes.